# Proper Setup of WebSite/WebApplication Deployment on IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-7.5

I have inherited a project which is currently in the middle of migrating from some older ASP.NET technologies (a mixture of ASP, .NET 2 WebForms, etc.) to MVC, .NET 4. Quite a bit of the site is ported over, which is great. At this point, the MVC site is going to take full, front-and-center, with the older site pages being available from links within the site.

The way I am attempting to set this up is to have the new, MVC code be the site (e.g. Default Web Application, for example) and the various, older projects to be web applications underneath that site.

The first part has been deployed and works - the MVC site works great. But, I am having some difficulty with the older pages. For example, I setup a web application underneath the site called with the path GenerateReports and pointing to the appropriate directory (C:/OldProjects/GenerateReports/). When I browse to that part of the site (http://www.example.com/GenerateReports/BrowseReports.aspx), I receive an error that says:

> Configuration Error Description: An error occurred during the
>   processing of a configuration file required to service the request.
>   Please review the specific error details below and modify your
>   configuration file appropriately.
>
> [-snip-]
>
> < compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"> ...

The strange thing is - that line is in my MVC's Web.config (which is built using .NET 4.0) - not in the older, web app's web.config (which is .NET 2.0). That is if I have the AppPool for the old web application set to .NET 2.0.

If I set the AppPool to .NET 4.0 (for the older web application), then I receive this error:

> The value for the 'compilerVersion' attribute in the provider options
>   must be 'v4.0' or later if you are compiling for version 4.0 or later
>   of the .NET Framework. [-snip-]

The first problem seems "closer to correct," but I can't find anything on Google that really describes what the problem is and, more importantly, how to fix it. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are the subsites setup in IIS as applications?

Comment: Yes. They are web applications underneath the main site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I think I figured this out...

I setup the server so that the site is the MVC site. Everything within that MVC site works/starts correctly, so that was a success.

I then began adding Web Applications underneath the site with each application being one of the ASP, WebForms applications. I had to do a little bit of configuration - specifically, I had to use the information found on [Scott Hanselman's blog on mixing child applications](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ChangingASPNETWebconfigInheritanceWhenMixingVersionsOfChildApplications.aspx) - to prevent the settings from "trickling down" into the web applications.

Finally, for the classic ASP pages (of which there are a few left), I had to provide virtual folders to those locations (again, underneath the site) and I had to enable ASP on my server (*not* ASP.NET which was already enabled for everything else). I also had to enable parent paths in the ASP settings for the top-level site in order for the ASP pages to work correctly. Of course, I will be working to convert the rest of the ASP pages to MVC ASAP and I can then completely remove support for it.

Hopefully this helps someone else!